# Proving function of Brownian motion is a martingale

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

In a question we're given, are given $X_t= \int_0^t sB_s dB_s$ for $B_s$ being Brownian motion. We are first told to find $\text{Var}(X_t)$, which I compute using Ito's Lemma to be $\frac{t^4}{4}$. Then, we seek to show in the second part that $$\sqrt{B_t^2 + 10} - 5\int_0^t \frac{ds}{(B_s^2 + 10)^{3/2}}$$ is a martingale. I mentioned the earlier part just in case it's relevant to proving this martingale fact, which is what we ultimately seek to prove. I think proving finite absolute means is doable, but I'm not sure how to proceed in showing the martingale property. I tried using linearity to split into two conditional expectations, and using Ito's Lemma on the second, but not sure where to go from there or how to make that work. In particular, I don't know how to rewrite the above functions of $B_t$ as a function of $B_s$ for some $s < t$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Not sure it can work but my first idea would be to let $Y_t := \sqrt{B_t^2+10}$ and apply Itô's lemma to it. Then the process $Z_t$ which you want to prove is a martingale is a solution of
$$dZ_t = dY_t - 5 \frac{dt}{Y_t^3} $$
So possibly applying Itô's lemma one more time could yield something interesting

Answer (score 1):

StratosFair's suggestion is a good one.

Let $Y_t = \sqrt{B_t^2 + 10}$ so that, by Ito's formula, after a bit of rearranging, $dY_t = B_tY_t^{-1}dB_t + 5Y_t^{-3}dt$.

Then $dZ_t = B_tY_t^{-1}dB_t$. We know that an Ito integral against a Brownian is a (local) martingale, so we are done.